# Setting up linq db connection string

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I created a connection using the server explorer, and dragged my entire database over (all tables) to the designer.

I want linq to use my connection string in the web.config when I deploy it, how do I make it do this instead of using the connection string created in the server explorer?

Answer (score 1):

```
YourContextClass context = new YourContextClass(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yourconectionstringid"].ConnectionString);
```